# Transact SQL trying to avoid duplicates using inner joins and "Like" constraint

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT numSerie, nomVehicule,model,AnneeModel 
FROM Vehicule,Marque where Vehicule.idMarque = Marque.idMarque and Vehicule.numSerie 
LIKE "%" OR Marque.nomVehicule LIKE "%"
```

this display something like this, it duplicates results

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0vuX.jpg)

if you remove this part of code it works just fine

```
 OR Marque.nomVehicule LIKE "%"
```

[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlgSl.jpg)

Comment: so why you don't just remove this part?)

Comment: it is necessary for my application

Comment: The header says that the question about **Transact SQL**, but it is tagged by **MySQL**... What is the question about?

Comment: trying to avoid duplicates

Comment: To avoid duplicates just use DISTINCT (DISTINCTROW) keyword or GROUP BY clause.

Comment: already tried it doesn't work

Comment: @AyoubElHafi, belive be, that part that you dont want to remove is not essential, you have a trouble with data, and with basics of SQL

Comment: it essential for search purposes you can search by numSerie or nomVehicule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHERE clause needs some work. Look at the boolean logic. When you don't enclose conditions in parenthesis, it evaluates the boolean operators left-to-right.

Switching to ANSI-92 SQL notation would solve the problem immediately. ANSI-92 notation is 25 years old and while database engines still run queries with older join notation just fine, using ANSI-92 join notation would have avoided this problem completely.

```
 FROM Vehicule,Marque 
WHERE (Vehicule.idMarque = Marque.idMarque) 
  AND ((Vehicule.numSerie LIKE "%") OR (Marque.nomVehicule LIKE "%"))
```

Or even better, in ANSI-92 notation::

```
 FROM Vehicule
      JOIN Marque ON (Vehicule.idMarque = Marque.idMarque)
WHERE Vehicule.numSerie LIKE "%" OR Marque.nomVehicule LIKE "%"
```